# Should I delete my question if it had mistakes?

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions

I had posted a question, but later realised through the comments and the answers, that my question's fundamental assumptions were wrong.

When this happens on other platforms, I delete my question but I tell people to not delete their answers. But I don't think that is possible in Stack

So should I delete my question because it isn't a proper one, or should I leave it so that other people with similar misconceptions can see the answers (and so that the people who answered don't lose reputation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Comment: I understood how the normal deletion criteria and procedures work, but that doesn't answer my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should heavily-edited answers block self-deletion of questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276027/should-heavily-edited-answers-block-self-deletion-of-questions) - yes both do.

Comment: See also: "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/282094)", "[Does Stack Exchange allow for answers which question the validity or stance of the original question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263661/282094)" and "[Is  “Don't do it” a valid answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8891/282094)". --- It ought to be VLQ to be deleted, or a duplicate that is so close to another that it adds no value to the site and future visitors. Questions deleted for reasons that others don't agree with are subject to undeletion. Questions with upvoted answers can't be deleted.

Comment: @Rob Thanks, those were helpful, but they didn't completely answer my question.The specific situation that made me ask this question is a mathematics question. I had made an assumption that functions of the form f(x)/g(x) are polynomial functions. But actually, it's a rational function, making the rest of the question meaningless. I received 1 comment and 1 answer telling this to me. So I wanted to know if I should've deleted the question or not. But as others answered in this post, I should've just edited my question telling that it had a mistake, without deleting it

Comment: @AndhavarapuBalu It would probably have improved this question if you had included the example question in [your last comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364104/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-had-mistakes?noredirect=1#comment1216307_364104) rather than leaving it to a general answer useful to the most amount of people; now you can't change this question and invalidate the work done in the answers offered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No,

Do not delete questions just because **you** got an answer.

Ask yourself: *Is it likely that a future visitor will follow a similar thought process, make similar assumptions and end up with the same wrong conclusion as I did?*

If you expect that might be true then your question (and its answers) have value and some day in the future someone else will benefit from your and others effort. Check your question to make sure it has the key elements clearly worded so Google can index it.

On the other hand, if you think no-one will ever land on the same issue again then a question and the answers don't have lasting value except for you. Deletion is then an option, assuming you didn't receive positive scoring answers.

It is worth noting that deleting questions can cause the quality mechanisms to kick-in. Asking and then deleting too many questions risks your account getting either rate limited or quality-banned, allowing you only one question every six months.

Optimize for future visitors is the best advice I can give.

Comment: Would people normally downvote my question because of the wrong assumptions?

Comment: @AndhavarapuBalu people vote on content for all kind of reasons. They often do expect content to be well researched and clear.

Answer (score 4):

If the people who answered your question have reputation to lose from their answers then you are unlikely to be able to delete it.

In any event, I think you need to be mindful of existing answers whenever you edit a question after they have been posted.  It is fine to improve your question, as long as you do not invalidate any of its answers that address what you had asked.

However, as [commented by @rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364104/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-had-mistakes#comment1215054_364105), a better place for addressing any incorrect assumptions in your question, that influenced their answer, may be in a self-answer to it that starts by pointing out the incorrect assumption(s).

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, I think that the proper option would be not to delete the question and to edit it, adding a sentence or two in which you explain that now you think that the question's fundamental assumptions were wrong and why.

Comment: Isn't *the question's fundamental assumptions were wrong and why.* answer territory and by adding it to the question, you're basically writing an "answer" in your question? If the question is lacking any info or guidance why the OP made this assumption then that might need to be clarified so visitors indeed recognize that they share the same assumption. Why that is "wrong"  can then be found in the answer(s).